# Magento 2 set locale programmatically?

Tags: magento2, language

i am create one test php file in magento root directory.
i install ar_SA Language pack and try to convert one string English to Saudi Arabia here is my test code.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$localeInterface = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface');
$localeInterface->setLocale('ar_SA');
echo $localeInterface->getLocale(); // it's print ar_SA

echo __('Check Value');
```

I have the corresponding translation in /i18n/ar_SA.csv file, it doesn't print the translated sentence.

Comment: Please check your csv file some times that is issue if it having any spaces like that and format is different like utf-8.I have installed 2 new languages in my site  both working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using Resolver Interface.

```
$localeInterface = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface');

$localeInterface->setLocale('ar_SA');
$localeInterface->setDefaultLocale('ar_SA');

echo __('Check Value');
```

This is working in my case. 
if you have any query ask me.

Comment: I'm using the same code but I still get the translation in English, did you make any other changes ? Thanks !

Comment: @magentodev did you get any solutions for the same ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use translation on external php script. You have to initialize translation using following code after `$state->setAreaCode('frontend');`.

```
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader')->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

Full script will be like

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader')->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);

echo __('Check Value'); // will be print translated value if defined in language csv.
```

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the `setLocale()` but check in your `js-translation.json` if your translation is really in that file.

If not you need to delete all `js-translation.json` and redeploy static content for that locale at least.

If it is still not in that file you need to paste your translation module or theme code. Ie. I don't see a /i18n/ar_sa/... subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I do it pretty much the same but with one more call on the $localeInterface

```
$localeInterface = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface');
$localeInterface->setLocale('de_DE');
$localeInterface->loadData();
```

ant it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the locale and set the correct renderer to Phrase class because by default it uses just Placeholder ( Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Placeholder ).

So something like this should work:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(Http::class);
$om = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

///** @var Magento\Framework\App\State $state */
$state = $om->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$state->setAreaCode(Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

$translate = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\Translate::class);
$renderer = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Translate::class);

$translate->setLocale('de_DE');
$translate->loadData('global', true);
$placeHolder = \Magento\Framework\Phrase::getRenderer();

$composite = new \Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Composite([
    $renderer, $placeHolder
]);

\Magento\Framework\Phrase::setRenderer($composite);

echo __('"%1" is not a valid email address.', 'Email');
```